# Azure Storage account consistently only adding Blob storage, missing Table/Queue/Files

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, azureportal

Whenever I create a new Storage (classic) account through the Azure portal I consistently have issues whereby the Table/Queue/File storage is not created at all, leaving the account with only Blob storage, like this:

[image]

Instead of like this (separate account):

[image]

I have tried this multiple times and all have had the same result. I don't see how I can be getting this wrong as there is only 4 options on the form to create the account, and none of them govern the content of the account.

When I then attempt to create a new Table or Queue in this new account I get a `502 Bad Gateway` error.

Am I missing something here? Can anyone tell me how I can add the required storage types to the account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what's up with the portal, but a storage account always comprises blob, table, queue, and file storage (unless you create a Premium storage account - that's strictly blobs).

You should be able to confirm this by creating an app to, say, create, write, and read from a queue or table.

**EDIT** I see you edited your question, showing that you *did* try to create a table/queue. If this is a non-premium account, I suggest reaching out to support, as this makes no sense.

**EDIT 4/2017** Aside from Premium storage accounts (which only have page blobs), there is another type of general (non-premium) storage account, specific to blobs only, where you won't be able to create Tables and Queues, but it's not available via the "Classic" deployment model; it's available only via "Resource Manager" deployment model:

[image: blob-only storage account]

Comment: `unless you create a Premium storage account - that's strictly blobs` That's the issue then - I attempted to create this as a premium account expecting the performance to be scaled up/out over 'standard'. Exactly what difference does a 'premium' account make?

Comment: Premium storage is SSD, specifically for creating blob-backed VHD disks (from 128GB to 1TB per disk). There's no SSD-based table or queue service available.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the issue was due to selecting Zone Redundant Storage (ZRS).

> Since ZRS accounts only support Block Blobs, you will not see the
>   table, queue or file endpoints listed on the portal for the new
>   account.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2014/08/01/introducing-zone-redundant-storage/

Recreating the storage account using Globaly Redundant Storage (GRS) worked.